# find and replace element in file using python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning `python` and in the code below I am trying to replace all values where `"id": null,` with `"id": na,`...
there may not always be an `id` in every block. If `c` does not have that pattern in it then it is skipped. Thank you :)

**file**

```
{
 "objects": [
    {
        "version": "1",
        "id": null,
        "date": 1,
         ...,
    },
    {
        "version": "1",
        "id": 1xx1,
        "date": 1,
         ...,
    },
```

**desired**

```
{
"objects": [
    {
        "version": "1",
        "id": na,
        "date": 1,
         ...,
    },
    {
        "version": "1",
        "id": 1xx1,
        "date": 1,
         ...,
    },
```

**python3**

```
import json

with open('file.json',encoding='utf8') as in_file:
data = json.load(in_file)

for c in data['objects']:      # read all elements in object into c
if c = "\"id\""\: null,:       # check to see if element in c is "id": null,
    data[c] = "\"id\""\: na,   # replace c with
```

Comment: I dont think `na` is a valid json value. You could just use `replace`/`re.replace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error is in following code

```
if c = "\"id\""\: null,:       # check to see if element in c is "id": null,
    data[c] = "\"id\""\: na,   # replace c with
```

As @Dan-Dev mentioned, the null in c#, c++, etc. is `None` in Python. You can use this code and read my code as side information to understand more.

```
import json

with open('file.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

for obj in data['objects']:
    if obj.get('id') is None:
        obj['id'] = 'na'
        # if you want to write back
with open('data.json', 'w') as file:

    json.dump(data, file, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `None` in python for a `NoneType` not `null` i.e. `if not obj['id']:` but `None` is `falsy` so you can just use `if not`

```
import json


with open('file.json', encoding='utf8') as in_file:
    data = json.load(in_file)
for obj in data['objects']:
    if not obj['id']:
        obj['id'] = 'na'
print(data)
```

`"id": an` is invalid as Json and in a Python dictionary I think you want to either initialise `an` as a variable or use a string `"id": "an"`

Or more concisely use comprehensions:

```
import json


with open('file.json', encoding='utf8') as in_file:
    print(json.dumps({'objects': [{k: 'na' if k == 'id' and not v else v for k, v in entry.items()} for entry in json.load(in_file)['objects']]}))
```

As @Mohamed Fathallah suggests use `json.dump()` to write the data to a file or `json.dumps()` to display it as a json formatted string.